# Лучший способ зациклить try /catch в моем случае

Tags: java

Предложите адекватный способ зациклить каждый поиск элемента и клик по нему. (Зачем это нужно просьба не спрашивать. данном случае, это единственный способ) 
С goto было бы все красиво, но увы.. 
 Выводить каждый поиск элемента в отдельный метод тоже не красиво. У меня пару десятков таких элементов, а если каждый из них оборачивать кодом для метода, то всё выглядит плохо.

```
 public static void findElement() {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
            element.click();

            WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label");
            element1.click();

            WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.id(""));  
            element2.sendKeys(elementsOfTheApplication.getC());

            try {
             goto:   WebElement element3 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("s']"));
                element3.click();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //переход на goto
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

            WebElement element4 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("]"));
            element4.click();

            WebElement element5 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("l-']"));
            element5.click();
    }
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3aqmRpDQ ?

Comment: Но, я не верю что других путей решения нет. Скорее всего вы что то не так делаете.

Comment: попробуйте сделать универсальный метод с каллбеком. Так вы упростите конструкции и избавитесь от одинакового кода. В теле каллбека можно будет указывать что нужно сделать - кликнуть, или послать нажатие клавиши. Далее, можно реализовать пару тривиальных каллбеков, и всё, половина кода автоматизирована, а тело вашей функции будет состоять из понятных и простых команд

Comment: "Выводить каждый поиск элемента в отдельный метод тоже не красиво." - всего то два метода получится. Один для find + click, другой для find + sendKeys. И у обоих параметром будет то, что вы передаете в findElement. И никаких колбеков не нужнно, как вам выше написали. Goto- это адская хрень, очень старнно видеть "с goto было бы все красиво" еще и в сравнени с функциями. Вон вам как минимум один вариант предложили, я еще могу предложить что-то в духе while(isSuccess) - будет нагляднее. А имена element1, element2 - второе место по кошмару после goto. Две худшие практики в одном вопросе - сильно )

Comment: А есть еще более красивый вариант, если вы вынесите в функцию, то можно очень красиво через рекурсию сделать https://pastebin.com/5uazghi3 . Но с этим аккуратно, можно схлопотать StackOverwlowException

Comment: test123, дело в том, что я делаю поиск элемента и он находится, в это время страница продолжает видоизменяться(javascript) и элемент расположенный в массиве элементов меняет свой id. Может и не совсем верно понимаю, в веб не разбираюсь. НО тот факт, что оказывается В джаве можно заюзать StaleTolerantWebDriver decorator, который как раз и решает подобные проблемы, путем повтора поиска элемента, если словили StaleReferenceElementException. Выходит велосипедик я  пишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитав внимательно ваши комментарии написал такой вариант решения: 
 три статических метода в классе созданном как Модель объекта

```
private static void FindClick(By by) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
                element.click();
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void FindSend_keys(By by, String key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
                element.sendKeys(key);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void FindClearSendKeys(By by, String key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            try {
                WebElement element = driver.findElement(by);
                element.clear();
                element.sendKeys(key);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```